# How to print Char matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix, char

I'm very new to c++, so excuse me for my stupid question.
I can't print char matrix.

This is my code. I must not use strings!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int sizeX = 3;
    const int sizeY = 3;

    char matrix[sizeX+1][sizeY+1] = { {'a','b','c', '\0'},{'d','e','f', '\0'},{'g','h', 'k', '\0'}};

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeX; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeY; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix[sizeX][sizeY]);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
}
```

I found a lot of information about int matrix but nothing about char matrix, and i can't find my mistake.

Comment: `printf("%c ", matrix[i][j]);` and why are you mixing `printf()` and `std::cout` at all?

Comment: Or just `std::cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';` Note that I use the loop variables as index!

Comment: And what you're really creating is an array of strings, which could be better expressed as `std::string array[] = { "abc", "def", "ghi" };` And it could then be printed, character by character, like `for (auto const& str : array) { for (auto c : str) { std::cout << c << ' '; } std::cout << '\n'; }`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you, when I replace [sizeX] and [sizeY] with [i] and [j], it's done!

Comment: Are you sure you mean a "char matrix" isn't it just an array of [strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)? E.g. [`std::array<std::string,3>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or  more resizable a [`std::vector<std::string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). For formatting strings stop using printf and start using [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format). Also stop using `using namespace std;`. Can you tell us what source you use to learn C++  from, it seems a bit outdated.

Comment: Note if you can't use strings then someone is not teaching you C++ and I'd like to talk to your teacher.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you wrote when you print,`printf("%d ", matrix[sizeX][sizeY]);`

You just always print `matrix[sizeX][sizeY]`. So what's the point of having all these cycles?

To fix this, you need to change it into `printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);`

Also, if you want to print a char instead of the ASCII of the char. You need to change `%d` into `%c`.

In the end, I advise that do not use `cout` or `cin` while you are using `printf()` or `scanf()`

Best wishes to your coding road.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print indexes `sizeX` and `sizeY`, when you actually want to print indexes `i` and `j`.

You are also using `%d` in `printf`, which is used for integers. `%c` is used for characters.

Also, there is no need to be mixing `printf` and `std::cout` here. These 2 examples do the same thing:

- `printf("%c ", matrix[i][j]);`
- `std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";`